# What is the correct mapping to download a zipball from the repo of a private org using GitHub v3 API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I'm trying to pull, but failing, to download a zipball file from a private org's repo using my GitHub personal acct token that has the proper permissions to pull in the GitHub WebUI and a GitHub v3 API endpoint. According to this doc (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-a-repository-archive-zip), the proper syntax to use is  `https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/zipball/REF`.

But when push goes to shove and I modify it to a private org, I wind up something closer to this:

```
https://api.github.com/<private_org_name>/<private_repo_name>/zipball/<branch_name>
```

Which still doesn't work. The correct URL to download via WebUI is somewhere closer to this:

```
https://github.com/<private_org_name>/<private_repo_name>/archive/refs/heads/<branch_name>.zip
```

Does anyone happen to know what the correct API endpoint URL would be for a private repo for a private org?